# Where is written that name of Lord Vishnu or Venkateswara is Balaji?

Tags: scripture, vishnu, venkateshwara

Where in the Hindu scriptures of Vaishnava sects or Vishnu Sahasranama written that name of Lord Vishnu is Balaji? It appears that this is not the name of Shri Vishnu or Venkateswara